# Simple Forum Engine with Support for SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, forum

I need a simple forum backed by a SQLite 3 database which I can easily integrate into my new project, something in the line of [Vanilla forum](http://vanillaforums.org/).

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the features of all popular forums here http://www.forummatrix.org/wizard.php

Answer (score 2):

The [SQLite Users page](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteUsers) lists a few forums for use with SQLite (honest, no idea how up-to-date the list is, though):

> - [PunBB](http://www.punbb.org/): a message forum package, like phpBB but leaner, written in PHP
> - {[phpBB](http://phpbb.com/)} supports SQLite from phpBB version 3 (currently in beta)
> - {[Monkey Boards](http://sourceforge.net/projects/monkeyboards/)}
> - {[Pocoo](http://www.pocoo.org/)}
> - [BookGoldMine.com](http://www.bookgoldmine.com/): A website with a large collection of links to a large number of free books and lectures. Back end is SQLite 3 & SQLite.net.

Comment: bookgoldmine has a forum engine where? looks like they inserted themselves for seo purposes

Answer (score -1):

[Here it is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software_(PHP)#Data_storage), not sure which ones support SQLite 3 thought.